# Installing Dummynet on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, ipfw

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to install dummynet. I cannot however find a tutorial for Ubuntu. I've tried to follow this tutorial http://goo.gl/ZzKrpk however I get an error when making a kernel path.

```
$ make KERNELPATH=/usr/src/kernels/3.11.0-18-generic
echo target is all
target is all
(cd ipfw && make all )
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/pamlens/ipfw3-20120119/ipfw'
Makefile:16: Building userland ipfw for  Linux
cc -O1 -Wall -include ../glue.h -I ./include_e -I ./include -D__BSD_VISIBLE -Werror -I/usr/include -DNO_ALTQ   -c -o ipfw2.o ipfw2.c
ipfw2.c: In function ‘show_ipfw’:
ipfw2.c:976:18: error: variable ‘altqptr’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [ipfw2.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pamlens/ipfw3-20120119/ipfw'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Same problem reported here, not a cross post, but if anyone figures this one out they can A that one too: http://superuser.com/questions/747559/install-dummynet-in-ubuntu-x64

Comment: These instructions show how to compile it. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1337587

Comment: It seems dummynet doesn't run smoothly on newer kernel versions. I downgraded my  kernel to 2.6.38-8 generic and it worked fine.